# Using aircrack-ng within VoCore

Tags: wifi, linux, microprocessors

I wonder if I can use VoCore to capture and create/inject custom made packages.

I'm a big fan of IoT. But I don't do this for a living. I'm just learning stuff, on my own, in my spare time. My background is as a java developer with some CCNA knowledge and other stuff.

So, I played around with aircrack-ng. With an Alfa AWUS036NH dongle. It can inject packages and be used with all that. I cannot use something else, as this has all the capabilities I need, some of which not related to the subject.

Now. I wanna size down my project. And found the VoCore: http://vocore.io/v2.html and I'm not sure what chipset should be used.

What I want to do is send custom-made packages with these two. Or 'listen' for certain packages. I should specify that my end goal are the way packages are constructed. So this hardware might not be the best choice.

Getting back to my question: how can I do this keeping the size very small? What implications on these small units? I can very well do all this with my pc. or a raspberry, but on VoCore. can I even run airodump on it? Will it be any different, regarding performance. regarding a feasible outcome? Should I try something else?

The traffic is very small, so high speed does not matter. A few pointers into the right direction. would suffice. I can take it from there.

Again, thanks so much and my apologies for the naïve approach.

Comment: This remains both far **too broad** and **off-topic**.  While someone very familiar with building for the MT76xx in the vocore environment could likely port the software you want to run, the process of doing so does not belong here, and is too involved for *any* stack exchange site.  You need to pursue this with vocore resources or resources for the software you want to utilize, **this site is neither of those places**.  To get a sense of what you are up against, you might visit the community site for the similar-hardware Onion Omega2 and see the complication of projects like this.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! Meanwhile I have found a way to do this. Or at least in part... but it's a start. I will be more careful with my next questions.

Comment: @CatalinPodariu glad to hear you found a solution!  We'd appreciate seeing that solution if you could post it in the answer box below.

Comment: @Helmar why was this re-opened?  It's never been an IoT question that in any way belonged here, and its abandonment by even the asker demonstrates it's not going to be resolved.